# Android Launch Activity ActionBar

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar

Could anyone anyone tell why my launch activity does not `ActionBar` title before it is visible?

First it shows an ActionBar with app title for half a second and only then changes it to some custom text. I am using *ActionBarSherlock* and changing ActionBar title from `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)`.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    activityName = context.getClass().getSimpleName();
    if (activityName.equals("LaunchActivityName")) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Custom title");
        getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("Custom subtitle");
    }

    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    return true;
}
```

Could anyone suggest how this situation could be avoided?

Comment: Post your source code.

Comment: are you sure the text you set in onCreateOptionsMenu() is the good one? post some code, this should be easy to fix.